# jquery - refer submit button to the right js code

Tags: jquery

i have 2 forms in 1 page and 2 js files that allow me to submit them with ajax.

How do I refer each submit button to the right js code?

```
<form id="login-form" class="modal-content" action="#">
    <button id="submitLoginButton" class="btn btn-success">SEND LOGIN FORM</button>
</form>

<form id="reg-form" class="modal-content" action="#">
    <button id="submitRegButton" class="btn btn-success">SEND REG FORM</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

file 1:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    //code for **login** form
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

});
```

file 2:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {

    //code for **registration** form
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

});
```

Comment: Why are you binding generic `form` submit event handler?

Comment: use id in submit function like `$(document).on('submit','#login-form',function(e) {`

Comment: The forms has id, so use the ID selector

Comment: @Satpal - can you give me example?

Comment: A submit button submits the form it is a part of. I think what you're looking for is to fill in your action within the form element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use id of your form instead of tag only. You can do it like this:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    //code for **login** form
});
```

Don't remember to use this code after page loading:

```
$(function(){
    // this code will be processed after page loading
});
```